# Dimension containers when plotting Holoviews Curve and spread overlay in Holomap

Tags: python-3.x, holoviews

With the script below I expected to get a dropdown menu for changing the slope. i.e only showing one of the plots, not all three.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

slope = [1, 5, 10]

def curve(slope):
    x = np.linspace(1,10)
    y = slope*0.5+x
    err = x*0.2
    return hv.Curve((x, y)) * hv.Spread((x,y,err))


curve_dict = {r:curve(r) for r in slope}

kdims = hv.Dimension(("slope", "slope"))

hmap = hv.HoloMap(curve_dict, kdims=kdims).overlay()
hmap
```

This return the following plot:

[image]

What am I missing here? I expected a dropdown menu, not all three graphs showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You turned your holomap into an [overlay()](http://holoviews.org/reference/containers/bokeh/Overlay.html) which basically means putting the plots on top of eachother.

When you remove the .overlay() you get the slider to select your plot:

```
hmap = hv.HoloMap(curve_dict, kdims=kdims)
```